# search used resources through page and remove them

Tags: java, pdfbox

I use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442109/pdfbox-how-to-import-acrofield-from-another-pdf?answertab=active#tab-top) to export acroform to new pdf file from another source pdf.

The result pdf with acroform only you can [download here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15tW_o8A3inEHPRVPXyjXqqEX3zNsgwWf)

I used pdfcompressor online website to compress this pdf(59Ko) and I reduce it -64%.
This website seems to clean all unused things inside Resources, here is screenshot from PDFDebugger

[image: screenshot from PDFDebugger]

My question is how can I get a xobject or font from Resources[] and check if they are used somewhere in page if not delete it from Resources[].

If it is complicated to search in PDPage if some resources are used or not, how can I simply remove XObject or Font from Resources[] ?

While it is out of scope to me to search used xobject in page I just tried direct deletetion of COSObject but it not works ^^ :

```
        for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {

            PDResources resources = page.getResources();

            // all xobject form resources
            for (COSName name : resources.getXObjectNames()) {
                page.getCOSObject().removeItem(name); // NOT WORKS
            }

            // all font resources from pages
            for (COSName name : resources.getFontNames()) {
                if (resources.getFont(name) instanceof PDFont) {
                    page.getCOSObject().removeItem(name); // NOT WORKS
                }

            }
        }
```

ps: question created after @mkl recommendation [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53420344/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-merged-pdf-a-1b-files-with-pdfbox-or-other-java-librar/53544377?noredirect=1#comment97549084_53544377)

### update1

Here is the current code I have to extract acroform from a pdf:
// create FORM from original

```
PDDocument documentSrc = PDDocument.load(new File("original.pdf"));;
PDAcroForm acroFormSrc = documentSrc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

PDDocument documentDest = new PDDocument();
for (PDPage page : documentSrc.getPages()) {
    PDPage destPage  = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
    destPage.setMediaBox(page.getMediaBox());
    destPage.setCropBox(page.getCropBox());
    documentDest.addPage(destPage);
}

PDAcroForm acroFormDest = new PDAcroForm(documentDest);


acroFormDest.setCacheFields(true);
acroFormDest.setFields(acroFormSrc.getFields());
documentDest.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroFormDest);

int pageIndex = 0;
for (PDPage page : documentSrc.getPages()) {
    documentDest.getPage(pageIndex).setAnnotations(page.getAnnotations());
    // after disabling this size increase
    //documentDest.getPage(pageIndex).setResources(page.getResources());
    pageIndex++;
}

acroFormDest.setDefaultAppearance(acroFormSrc.getDefaultAppearance());
acroFormDest.setDefaultResources(acroFormSrc.getDefaultResources());
acroFormDest.setQ(acroFormSrc.getQ());

// this is disabled because setResources is disabled above
//removeLinksInPages(documentDest);
//removeTextInDocument(documentDest);
```

This result : [pdf without resources](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1dxlGlHRRpyTtJtwMAJi5DNlxtJyxjIOQ&export=download)

This time form-without-resources is 73Ko while my original pdf is 75Ko.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Reducing the resources of *your* page objects

Well, I think your current task is much simpler than what you ask for in your question. I interpret your

> I use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48442109/pdfbox-how-to-import-acrofield-from-another-pdf?answertab=active#tab-top) to export acroform to new pdf file from another source pdf.

to imply that you really merely want to transfer the **AcroForm** fields and features from one PDF to another and are not interested in the static page content of the original file.

Thus, the answer to the question which *page resources you actually use* is simple: **None**! Page resources are resources used in the static content (in the page content stream) which you are not interested in.

Thus, there is no need to copy the page resources to your new document in the first place, simply remove the line

```
documentDest.getPage(pageIndex).setResources(page.getResources());
```

from the code in the referenced answer.

---

As an aside: @Tilman already had remarked in a comment to the answer you used as template that the resources of interest are the *"default resources of the acroform", not page resources*. Thus, you might not only want to copy the fields between the `PDAcroForm` instances:

```
acroFormDest.setFields(acroFormSrc.getFields());
```

but also default resources, default appearance, and default quadding

```
acroFormDest.setDefaultAppearance(acroFormSrc.getDefaultAppearance());
acroFormDest.setDefaultResources(acroFormSrc.getDefaultResources());
acroFormDest.setQ(acroFormSrc.getQ());
```

## Other issues

### Annotations referring back to wrong page

> This time form-without-resources is 73Ko while my original pdf is 75Ko.

Looking a bit deeper into your "form-without-resources.pdf" the problem becomes clear:

[image: screen shot]

As you see, you field widget annotations point back to the wrong page!

*That **P** value is specified as*

> **P**
>   dictionary
>   *(Optional except as noted below; PDF 1.3; not used in FDF files)* An indirect reference to the page object with which this annotation is associated.
>
> *(ISO 32000-1, Table 164 – Entries common to all annotation dictionaries)*

Thus, you set the annotations of your target page to the annotations of the source page but those annotations in their **P** value still reference the source page. As a consequence you drag along the source page with all its resource into your new document via this reference. So it does not surprise at all that your result file is not relevantly smaller than your source.

If you change your code to correct the **P** references, e.g. like this:

```
int pageIndex = 0;
for (PDPage page : documentSrc.getPages()) {
    PDPage destPage = documentDest.getPage(pageIndex);
    destPage.setAnnotations(page.getAnnotations());
    for (PDAnnotation annotation : destPage.getAnnotations())
        annotation.setPage(destPage);
    // after disabling this size increase
    //documentDest.getPage(pageIndex).setResources(page.getResources());
    pageIndex++;
}
```

*([CopyForm](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/CopyForm.java#L225) test `testCopyLikeBeeImproved`)*

you'll loose these references to the old data.

Comment: If my interpretation is wrong and you actually do need (parts of) the original static content, please clarify the question accordingly. Looking for used resources is also possible but a bit more difficult.

Comment: By the way, there is another issue with the annotation copying technique: the annotations have a reference back to their page. Thus, the code from that referenced answer indirectly also copies the original pages and with these original pages also the original resources. Thus, you should set the page property of the annotations to your page in the target document.

Comment: thank you! I updated my question according your answer and problem is I have no resources at page side but pdf size is bigger 73Ko im really facing into problem here out of scope. Yes You understand correctly, my requirement should be simple to understand I want extract acroform into new document, dont want other unused resources. I remember after passing this 73Ko to pdfcompressor it result in 22Ko, does here resources moved at another places? i can't follow

Comment: @bee See my edit to my answer: Your annotations still point back to the original page which, therefore, is dragged along into your result PDF. (I don't know whether your PDF has other references back there, too. If the above does not result in a significant decrease in size, please share your original file for better tests.)

Comment: you dude impressed me! You give always complet answer and always correct one! Donno how you know all these things ! Thank you a lot for consideration and all help you give to community!  I will confirm you tomorrow but it seems give me 22Ko. I still dont understand why this P is referencing to old page while it not exist in new doc but ok thank Ou

Comment: *"I still dont understand why this P is referencing to old page while it not exist in new doc"* - the objects describing the original page were included in the result pdf. But they are not referenced from the new document's **Pages** array. Thus, those old pages are not displayed in a viewer.